# Error in Ruby while installing spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello friends I am newbie in Rails.I installed rails in my ubuntu 10.10. As per my project requirement I installed
spree.Then I made application using command

```
rails new mystore
```

then I  created the store application, switched to its folder to continue work directly in that application with command 
    $ cd mystore
then I made install spree_sample by the command

```
rake spree_sample:install
```

After that I made populating my database with this command then it showed error like this

```
rake aborted!
syntax error on line 20, col -1: `test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: mystore_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:root


production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: mystore_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:root
```

I was using [this](http://spreecommerce.com/documentation/getting_started.html) site for reference.Just have a look on it.I want to make spree commerce in ruby on rails.So please help me.I am newbie to rails.

Comment: `rake spree_sample:install --trace` should get you some info on where the error is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in your database.yml config file. That's not related to Spree or to Ruby.
Should be "password: root" instead of "password:root"